# Is it possible to use js2-mode as javascript mode with nxhtml?

Tags: javascript, emacs

Is it possible to use js2-mode as javascript mode with nxhtml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not according to the author of js2-mode.

From [the source](http://js2-mode.googlecode.com/files/js2-20090723b.el):

```
;; This mode does not yet work with "multi-mode" modes such as mmm-mode
;; and mumamo, although it could possibly be made to do so with some effort.
;; This means that js2-mode is currently only useful for editing JavaScript
;; files, and not for editing JavaScript within <script> tags or templates.
```

Comment: and g-d help you if you convert your javascript into a single-line bookmarklet within js2-mode - the syntax-highlighting (or something like that) will kill your CPU. Js2-mode is VERY task-specific.

Comment: ps: js-mode is now in emacs23, it's probably the one you want.